# Sumar columna de tipo time en DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable

No estoy muy puesto de Ajax y necesito sumar los datos de una columna que almacena horas en formato H:i. Las columnas de mi DateTable son:

```
ajax: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{route('task.gp.list')}}',
            data: function (d) {
                d._token = token;
                d.from_date = from_date;
                d.to_date = to_date;
                d.department_id = $('#departments').val();
                d.end_worker = $('#end_worker').val();
                d.closed_tasks = $('#closed_tasks').val();
            }
        },
columns: [
            { data: 'deliverable', name: 'deliverable' },
            { data: 'subdeliverable', name: 'subdeliverable' },
            { data: 'incurred_hour', name: 'incurred_hour' },
            { data: 'total', name: 'total' },
            { data: 'on_time', name: 'on_time' },
            { data: 'off_time', name: 'off_time' },
            { data: 'kpi_d', name: 'kpi_d' },
            { data: 'agreed_count', name: 'agreed_count' },
            { data: 'disagreed', name: 'disagreed' },
            { data: 'kpi_q', name: 'kpi_q' }
        ],
```

La columna que tengo que sumar es la denominada 'incurred_hour' que está en forma H:i. En la siguiente imagen muestro lo que se carga en el DateTable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para otras columnas que no tienen formato de H:i (Cantidad finalizada) he utilizado la función reduce().

```
var total = api
    .column( 3 )
    .data()
    .reduce( function (a, b) {
        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
    }, 0 );
```

¿Alguién me puede indicar como debo hacerlo?

Un saludo.

Comment: Creo que falta información. No entiendo muy bien la referencia a Ajax. ¿Es con una llamada Ajax como obtienes los datos? ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de los datos recuperados?

Comment: Hola Kiko, gracias por tu comentario. He añadido una imagen del listado donde se puede ver el contenido de la columna Horas incurridas que quiero sumar.